# Determinism for networked games

Tags: networking

I am currently making a game project that will have players play together. And i am  basically planning to do it by only sending player inputs and have each client run the simulation on the pretence that the math will be fixed point throughout.

I am wondering if algorithms like A* path finding needs fixed point or are they naturally deterministic on any computer, what would the main cause of divergent behaviours be if i only sent clients data like this for pathfinders:

```
Player :: ID
Vector :: Start Point
Vector :: Target Point
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are really asking is whether a cost function in an optimization algorithm (like A*) can be sensitive to floating point error.

Yes it can be.  And results of an A* algorithm could therefore be non-deterministic if:

- paths were tried in a different order on different machines, or
- the different machines floating point hardware was different.

There are ways to mitigate these:

- use a deterministic implementation of the A* algorithm
- make sure that the different computers have identical inputs
- do computation using "strict" IEEE 754 floating point mode.

Now, if you only used integer values in the cost functions, you wouldn't have that problem.  But the simulation would be less realistic, I presume.

But hey ... what is wrong with non-determinism in a game or a simulation?  The real world typically isn't deterministic for the kind of complex systems you are talking about.  At least, not in a way that it we can show scientifically: you can't press the reset button on this morning's rush hour!

Comment: You say "use a deterministic implementation of the A* algorithm". Do you have pointers either to such implementations or how to make sure your implementation is deterministic? Also, you say, "what is wrong with non-determinism in a game or a simulation?" Well, if you want 2 systems to be in sync, they at least better be non-deterministic in the exact same way. Otherwise on one system player A might win a challenge, and on the other system Player B might also win it!

Comment: No I don't have specific pointers.  But this is really about how you *code* the algorithm; e.g. whether you iterate a "list" of alternatives in forward direction, in reverse direction, in parallel, etc.   You make sure it is deterministic by *code inspection* ... assuming that you understand the programming language you are using.

Comment: *"Well, if you want 2 systems to be in sync ..."* ... so maybe design the system so that it doesn't matter if the games are not exactly in sync.  Deal with the problem at a higher level.  Or call it "a draw".  Intractable problems are best solved by not trying to solve them.

Comment: @StephenC Depending on the game loss of synchronization can be very jarring.  If the game is moving an enemy unit and one client calculates its AI as moving it one way while the host or server moves it another, you end up with enemies that appear to teleport when the erroneous client resynchronizes.

Comment: So, maybe your idea of doing this in a distributed way is not viable.  Or maybe the errors will be small enough or infrequent enough that they do not matter.  What I have done is give you the facts.  It is up to you to figure out if you have a *real* problem here, and come up with the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am not sure i can enforce strict IEEE in C# on all clients. That would be handy if i could - would simplify my problem. I will try and see how realistic the results are using just integers for costs etc since that would also be a reasonably simpler solution.